# Inverse Laplace Transform in terms of error function by contour integration

Tags: calculus, functions

I am trying to find this by contour integration but I have no idea where to start because I'm supposed to do this in terms of the error function!

$$I= \int e^{-xt} \dfrac{\sin(a\sqrt x)}x dx$$

I'm sure that this is a laplace transform with $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin(a\sqrt x)}x dx$ but I'm definitely not sure on how to approach this. All help appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** Differentiate with regard to *t*, then let $x=u^2$, and use [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula).